# Перевал Гурзуфское седло или Гурзуфское Седло?

Tags: прописная-строчная, названия

С прописной или строчной буквы следует писать слово «седло»?

Comment: Может, всё-таки вы сможете не повторяться? ;) Имею в виду заголовок и сам текст вопроса.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой кстати говоря, есть такая проблема на сайте: иногда вопрос столь короток и конкретен, что вмещается в заголовок. Вот и приходится либо повторяться, либо изобретать филлерный заголовок, а сам вопрос писать в теле сообщения.

Comment: Это что, за то, что я продублировала вопрос и заголовие вопроса меня лишили ответа?

Comment: Нет, ответ исправляется, будет немного позже.

Comment: А! А то я уже подумала....за плохое поведение)...

Comment: Ахахах, ну вы и выдумщица!))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Перевал Гурзуфское Седло**.

Насколько я понял, *перевал* и *седло* не одно и то же, поэтому, [по правилу Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=17), *перевал Гурзуфское Седло* должен писаться именно так.
В Большой Российской энциклопедии перевал упомянут трижды, [все три раза *Седло* написано с прописной буквы.](https://bigenc.ru/search?q=%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%84%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE)

Answer (score 2):

Пишут и так и сяк. Думаю, что правильно – со строчной буквы: *перевал* ***Гурзуфское седло***.

Одно из значений слова «[**седло**](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE)» (Викисловарь):

> ***геол.*** изгиб пласта породы, по форме напоминающий седло, длинная впадина, неглубокая выемка между возвышениями горного хребта ◆ Порою между массами туч ослепительно сверкает **седло** Эльбруса и хрустальные зубья других гор — они вцепились в облака и пытаются удержать их. *Максим Горький, «Женщина», 1913 г. [НКРЯ]*

А теперь читаем Розенталя ([Географические названия](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=17)):

> В составных географических названиях существительные пишутся с прописной буквы, только если они утратили свое лексическое значение и называют объект условно: *Белая Церковь* (город), *Красная Горка* (город), *Чешский Лес* (горный хребет), *Золотой Рог* (бухта), *Болванский Нос* (мыс). Ср.: *залив Обская губа* (*губа* — ‘залив’), *отмель Куршская банка* (*банка* — ‘мель’).

Comment: «Гурзуфское седло (Гурбет-Дере-Богаз) — это понижение (седло?) между Гурзуфской яйлой и Бабуган-яйлой»

Comment: Собсно, насколько я понял, перевал и седло не одно и то же, поэтому, по правилу Розенталя, *перевал Гурзуфское Седло* должен писаться именно так. К тому же, замечу, в Большой Российской Энциклопедии этот перевал упомянут трижды, и все три раза *Седло* с большой буквы.

Comment: Выглядит как седло, по очертаниям....   тогда логичнее со строчной..... Может, есть еще сёдла, разные.... гурзуфские....еще где-нибудь в мире...

Comment: «седло Эльбруса»... в ответе.. ..седловина горы...но не название ведь, не топоним...

Comment: Про седло Эльбруса: я просто привёл статью полностью. // По поводу названия: мне кажется, впадина, выемка между возвышениями как раз и используются для перевала. Единообразия в написании нет, понимания прямого и переносного смысла тоже.

Comment: Я тоже так думаю...а как же Большая Российская энциклопедия в ответе Нектоида?

Comment: Никто вас не осудит ни за большую букву, ни за маленькую. А сначала я дал ответ однозначный - с большой, но когда посмотрел значения *седла*, изменил.

Comment: Да.... Спасибо!